# sqlalchemy reflecting table and inserting a row

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

im building a wrapper for a db_connector using sqlalchemy...

since im trying to stay generic i presume i wont know what tables il have and thus i cant use orm line of development.... trying to use the reflection system, where i reflect the table from the database and trying to create new Object from this table in order to insert the new info i got from user.

at the moment my func gets table_name as the table to insert into a new row and row_arguments, as list with arguments for new row...

im struggling creating new object of that table, more precise object of a row for the table, which i think if id manage doing that all would be swell and using session i would manage to add the new row.
my question is how can i create that kind of object from the things i pass? i got engine,Session,metadata in the class itself defined....

```
def insertRow(self,table_name,row_arguments):
    self.table = self.getTablesInDB(table_name)
    self.session = self.Session()

    class Test(object):
        pass

    mapper(Test,self.table)
    string =""
    for i in row_arguments:
        string += i
    insert = Test()
    self.session.add(insert)
    self.session.commit()
```

in middle of code i have lots of things i tried, nothing seem to succeedd.... im kinda hopeless and out of ideas, please help

idea is to not know with what kind of tables im facing before retrieving them by the way

Answer (score 2):

What if you try :

```
def insertRow(self,table_name,row_arguments):
    table = self.getTablesInDB(table_name)
    self.session = self.Session()

    # Considering row_arguents is a dict {"colname1":value, "colname2":value}
    insert = table(**row_arguments)

    self.session.add(insert)
    self.session.commit()
```

Comment: But if you want row_arguments to be a list you can use table(*row_arguments)
It depends on your constructors

Comment: doesnt work if i put insert = self.table 
i get the error 'Table' object is not callable
and if i use ur code without adding the self before the table i get 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'table' referenced before assignment

Comment: table should be the class of your model that inherits from Base.

Comment: ok so that worked and thx alot for that, but my idea was using reflection in the manner that i wont use a class that inherits from Base. as in not knowing  what tables im facing